# Prevent Case Status change validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

If the work item status is 'Done' and the case status is being changed to 'Cancelled,' there should be a validation rule that prevents this from happening.

Here is what I have:

```
AND( 
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Cancelled'), 
ISPICKVAL(Work_Item_Status__c, 'Done') 
)
```

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected
> Picklist, received Text

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that either `Status` or `Work_Item_Status__c` is a text field. Since `Status` is a standard picklist, we know it is in fact `Work_Item_Status__c` you are handling incorrectly. The correct way to check text equivalence in a formula is:

```
Work_Item_Status__c = "Done"
```